# How to remove Tile levelling clips (T-type) that have partially broken off?

Tags: bathroom, tile, grout

After laying my tile, some of the T-levelling clips broke off above the tile.

Unfortunately as a result I have small clip bits poking up above the tile. Any ideas on how to remove them before I grout?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Chisel, dremel? Grout saw?

Comment: As above or a utility knife?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Utility knife worked best, thanks for the suggestions.